# How to return the application when choosing 'NO' in SC_CLOSE of MFC

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mfc

I am using close x button in MFC. I used the code to handle with that even

```
void Main_MFCDlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{

    if(nID == SC_CLOSE)
    {
      if(MessageBox(_T("Are you ready to exit?"), _T("Message"), MB_YESNO) == IDYES);
        {
            // Exit here- Done
        }
      else
        {
         //Return application
        }

    }

    else
    {
        CDialog::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to click option 'No', then the application will still run. How to make the code to do that task? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return if you don't want to exit, or allow default processing:

```
void OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nID == SC_CLOSE)
    {
        if (MessageBox(_T("Are you ready to exit?"), _T("Message"), MB_YESNO) == IDNO)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    CDialog::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
}
```